# How to convert numbers in to date?

Tags: date

Bij splitting a string an array gives me following values back:

```
araay[1]=2
araay[2]=9
array[3]=2014
```

My question is how can i make from these 3 numbers a date 2-9-2014.
If i try:

```
var date = (array[1]-array[2]-array[3])
```

the return value is -2021 This is 2-9-2014=2021

```
var date = new Date (array[1]-array[2]-array[3])
```

the return value is 2

```
var date = new Date (array[1]-array[2]-array[3])
```

the reutrun value is 4-4-1908

So who can solve this?

Comment: You should tag your programming language too.

Comment: Unquoted `-` is *integer subtraction*, you want *concatenation*: `array[1] + "-" + array[2] + "-" + array[3]`

Comment: I recommend using a programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read basic string or char functionality for your chosen language.
Also this can be put in a class, predefined or not.
First you can try to use the - as chars instead of operators..

```
date = array[1] + "-" + array[2] + "-" + array[3]
```

but you should seriously just look at some documentation..
http://en.cppreference.com/w/